# SQL query to filter using where clause in same table but different filtering combinations in IF, ELSE scenario

Tags: sql

I want to get the records of a certain table (same table) by filtering in a kind of `IF ELSE` scenario. **if** the record/s are there, then fetch all the records, or if there are no record/s, use the **else** part in where clause and fetch the records.

The combination of `employee_id` and `address_id` should there and  **ONLY** records of one set of where combination should be fetched, not both.

```
SELECT * FROM employee WHERE
```

IF exists,

```
 employee_id ='1' AND address_id = '1'
```

ELSE

```
employee_id ='1' AND address_id = '*'
```

Comment: I would expect `employee_id` to be the primary key on a table called `employee`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff employee_id or address_id are not primary

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want something like this:

```
select e.*
from employee e
where e.employee_id = 1 and
      (e.address_id = 1 or
       not exists (select 1 from employee e2 where e2.employee_id = 1 and e2.address_id = 1);
  )
```

Comment: this does not fetch the data when the 2nd scenario exists and first scenario is not. Tried this query 
`SELECT * FROM OrderDetails od2
where od2.orderid = '10248' and
      (od2.productid = '13' or
       not exists (select 1 from OrderDetails od1
       where od1.orderid = '10248' and od1.productid = '42')
  );`
for the OrderDetails table in https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all
doesn't fetch data when the 2nd scenario exists